# How to load an image from a URL into a table section (with one row)?

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiimage

I have a table that consists of 6 sections, out of which my second section with 1 row should be loading an image from a URL.

I'm getting the URL from a plist file.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, I'm using the following code :

```
if let url = NSURL(string: park.getImageLink()) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {

                imageURL?.image = UIImage(data: data)

          }

//park.getImageLink() gets the URL of the image as a String from the plist file; var imageURL:UIImageView? is declared as a property
```

Further, I'm using a switch case to load the image into the correct section as :

```
  switch(indexPath.section){
          case PARK_IMAGE:
               cell?.imageView?.image = imageURL?.image
} // PARK_IMAGE's value is 1
```

When I run my code, I can see that my `contentsOfURL: url` has the correct URL, yet, my `imageURL?.image` is getting a nil.

Is my approach to load an image from a URL into a table section correct? If not, what am I missing, or what is the correct way to load an image into the table section? I'm new to Swift programming so I apologise if I'm making a newbie mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `data` non-nil? Are you sure the returned data actually represents an image and not some other HTML content? Paste the exact same URL into mobile Safari and see if you get the expected image.

Comment: Yep the image is there. And data is not nil, it shows a value in bytes, I'm guessing the image is being fetched fine.

Comment: It's not fine. If `data` actually represented a proper image, the `UIImage` wouldn't be `nil`. Did you try putting the exact URL of `url` into mobile Safari? Make sure you test on an iOS device and not your computer.

Comment: I tested the URL on the simulator and my iPhone's Safari, I can see the image there.

Comment: What kind of image is it? Maybe it's not supported by `UIImage`.

Comment: It is a JPEG format image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109858/discussion-between-user1650978-and-rmaddy).